# Problem with the filter in the django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im really confused. Why is this code not working ?

```
class EduUserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EduuserSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        if(self.kwargs != {}):
            test = EduUser.objects.filter(eduId=self.kwargs['pk'])
        else:
            test =  EduUser.objects.all()
        print(test)
        return test
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

[Here you can see the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW9Nv.png)

Comment: Assuming you are trying get object based on PK? Can you confirm this.

Comment: You are passing a long string (seems like a `UUID`) and it's not matching with the DB entry

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @RoopakANelliat Yes.

Comment: @JPG Its matching. You can see this on the picture

Comment: @Sayse The Method returns me an error 404.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the documentation for DRF Model Viewset.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Change your viewset to the following code.
DRF auto-generates the APIs required for you.

When you hit - `http://yourhost.com/api/eduuser/`, `list()` method is invoked.
And when you hit - `http://yourhost.com/api/eduuser/<pk>/`, `retrieve(pk)` method is invoked, which will return your object alone.

```
class EduUserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EduUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EduuserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        if isintance(pk, uuid.UUID):
            return self.get_serializer_class()(queryset.get(uuid_field=pk))
        return super(EduUserView, self).retrieve(request, pk, **kwargs)
```

The mistake from your side is that, you are trying to build something which is already build for you!! :P

Comment: The Problem is that the EduId is not the real PK. Its just an attribute which is unique

Comment: in that case you can override the retrieve method. Editting the answer.

Comment: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'eduuser.serializers.EduuserSerializer'>` Now i got this error

Comment: Change the return statement to - `return Response(data=self.get_serializer_class()(queryset.get(uuid_field=pk)).data)`
and dont forget to import `Response`